# Detect when a HTML5 Video runs full screen from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios

I received this request: https://github.com/Simbul/baker/issues/291

So I tried to look up if there was any event fired on Objective-C side from the UIWebView when the video began and stopped to be in full screen, in order to enable/disable again the orientation lock.

I'm aware this is possible in JavaScript:

```
var player = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
player.addEventListener('play',videoPlayHandler,false);
player.addEventListener('pause',videoPauseHandler,false);
```

but I would like to avoid injecting code in the page to detect it, since Baker is a framework and we allow any content running inside it.

Thanks in advance. :)